# How to round numbers to the nearest 1000?

Tags: python, rounding

I'm having some issue to round up and down of a list of number to the nearest 1000.

Below is my code:

```
rev_list = []

for i in range(12):
    rev = int(round(random.normalvariate(100000, 12000)))
    rev_list.append(rev)

print(rev_list)
```

The output is:

```
[97277, 96494, 104541, 132060, 98179, 87862, 84718, 95391, 94674, 89773, 92790, 86122]
```

I would like to round the list to the nearest 1000. How can I do that?

Answer (score 70):

[The `round` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) can take *negative* digits to round to, which causes it to round off to the *left* of the decimal. For example:

```
>>> round(15768, -3)
16000
>>> round(1218, -3)
1000
```

So the short answer is: Call `round` with the second argument of `-3` to round to the nearest 1000.

---

A minor warning since it surprises people: Python 3's `round` uses round-half-even rounding (also known as banker's rounding), and you're more likely to see "halves" when rounding to the left of the decimal. Basically, if input is exactly half-way between two possible values to round to, it will choose the value whose low non-zero digit is even. So:

```
>>> round(5, -1)  # Equally close to 0 and 10, but 1 is odd, so 0 chosen
0
>>> round(15, -1)  # Equally close to 10 and 20, but 1 is odd, so 20 chosen
20
```

On Python 2, it uses round-half-away-from-zero (and the result is always a `float`, even when rounding to negative digits), which is what most people were taught in school (but produces larger overall error when many values are rounded) so the same calls would produce `10.0` and `20.0` (and `round(-5, -1)` and `round(-15, -1)` would produce `-10.0` and `-20.0`, where Python 3 would get `0` and `-20`).

Comment: Note: My example behavior is the Python 3 behavior for `round`; if you're on Python 2, the results would be `float` values, but wrapping in `int()` would convert back to `int`.

Answer (score 3):

List comprehension is a one-line loop which allows you to apply a function to the list items. (for more read [List Comprehensions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0202/))

```
[x for x in rev_list]
```

In this case, round(num, -3) is the function.

```
>>> round(1300,-3)
1000
>>>
```

**The answer**

You can apply a function on a list by this code

```
rev_list=[round(x,-3) for x in rev_list]
```

The example:

```
>>> rev_list=[97277, 96494, 104541, 132060, 98179, 87862, 84718, 95391, 94674, 89773, 92790, 86122]
>>> rev_list=[round(x,-3) for x in rev_list]
>>> rev_list
[97000, 96000, 105000, 132000, 98000, 88000, 85000, 95000, 95000, 90000, 93000, 86000]
>>>
```

Comment: Usually it's better to explain a solution instead of just posting some rows of anonymous code. You can read [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), and also [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers)

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is better to explain how to solve the problem and provide the code as an example or reference. Code-only answers can be confusing and lack context.