# How to round up/down an int in Python?

Tags: python

Let's say I have an arbitrary integer 874,623,123 how do I round it down to 800,000,000 and up to 900,000,000? Another example is 759 round up to 800 or down to 700. The size of the integer is unknown.

Is there a built-in method to do it? If not, what's the best way to work it out? Sorry not a math expert here.

EDIT:
So far I have looked at

[Rounding down integers to nearest multiple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13082698/rounding-down-integers-to-nearest-multiple/13082705#13082705)

[Python round up integer to next hundred](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8866046/python-round-up-integer-to-next-hundred/8866125#8866125)

Both use a predefined divider

Comment: You can use https://stackoverflow.com/a/53975078/4180176 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/13082705/4180176. Honestly a quick google search brings up a bunch of solutions

Comment: It answers half of my question, doesn't go to the floor or ceiling.

Comment: + round up https://stackoverflow.com/a/8866125/4180176

Comment: @JoshuaNixon Honestly, if you read my question and read the answers you suggested, it doesn't answer my questions completely, your suggested answers assume a fixed rounding.

Comment: If you look at the answers, It is very easy to modify the solutions

Comment: Can you please [edit] to post which solutions you've already researched and tried. This will avoid people suggesting links and duplicates that does not work for you.

Comment: Though you're not saying so, it sounds like you want to round to one significant figure.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3411435/3890632

Comment: @khelwood they want to ciel/floor to one significant figure I guess

Comment: @khelwood thanks, I didn't know how to word it properly, it's not my first language, so I didn't use "significant number" to search for answers. Thanks, that's what I wanted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `math` module:

```py
import math

n = 874623123

# c contains the same number of digits as n
c = 10 ** int(math.log10(n))

print(math.floor(n/c) * c) # 800000000
print(math.ceil(n/c) * c)  # 900000000
```

Comment: I don' t know why, people having a bad day. I just gave you an upvote.

Comment: I did not downvote. An easier way is to pass a negative `digits` value to `round`.

Comment: Oh, sorry of the downvote. I thought I upvoted.

Comment: Nice but this only works for positive n, `math.log10(n)` will blow up on negative n. You need `math.log10(abs(n))` if n might be negative.